# Download Blobs from Azure using Python

Tags: python-3.x, azure

I need to extract the data from PDFs(millions) in Azure Storage to analyse and separate then in folders but it's too slow. It waste 11 minutes (just) to download 1000 PDFs. Is there any way to download it faster or to move/extract the data without having to download it?
I'm using `get_blob_to_path` to download the Blob and `slate3k` to convert the PDF to TXT.

Code(Sorry, there are some words in portuguese):

```
    block_service = BlockBlobService(account_name=ACCOUNT_NAME, account_key=ACCOUNT_KEY)

generator = block_service.list_blobs(CONTAINER_NAME, prefix="trt2", num_results=1000, timeout=60)

for blob in generator:

    path = "temp/" + blob.name.split("/")[-1]
    block_service.get_blob_to_path(CONTAINER_NAME, blob.name, path, timeout=60)

    with open(path, 'rb') as f:
        doc = slate3k.PDF(f)
        f.close()

        text_complete = ''
        for item in doc:
            item_pat = ''
            for line in item.split('\n'):
                item_pat += line + '\n'
            text_complete += item_pat

        text_complete = text_complete.strip().lower()



        if text_complete.find("acórdão") >= 0 and text_complete.find("acordam os magistrados") >= 0:
            print("Encontrei Acórdão")
            print("Arquivo "+path)
            block_service.create_blob_from_path(CONTAINER_NAME, "trt2/Acordao/" + arquivo, path)
            block_service.delete_blob(CONTAINER_NAME, blob.name)
            os.remove(path)
        elif text_complete.find("despacho") >= 0 and text_complete.find("conclusão") < 0 and text_complete.find("embargo") < 0 and \
                        text_complete.find("ata de audiência") < 0 and text_complete.find("termo de audiência") < 0 and \
                        text_complete.find("v o t o") < 0 and text_complete.find("certidão") < 0 :
            print("Encontrei Despacho")
            print("Arquivo "+path)
            block_service.create_blob_from_path(CONTAINER_NAME, "trt2/Despacho/" + arquivo, path)
            block_service.delete_blob(CONTAINER_NAME, blob.name)
            os.remove(path)
        elif text_complete.find("sentença") >= 0 and text_complete.find("relatório") >= 0 and \
                        text_complete.find("acordam") < 0 and text_complete.find("primeira testemunha") < 0 and \
                        text_complete.find("provas a produzir") < 0 and text_complete.find("embargo") < 0 and \
                        text_complete.find("voto") < 0:
            print("Encontrei Sentença")
            print("Arquivo "+path)
            block_service.create_blob_from_path(CONTAINER_NAME, "trt2/Sentenca/" + arquivo, path)
            block_service.delete_blob(CONTAINER_NAME, blob.name)
            os.remove(path)

        else:
            block_service.create_blob_from_path(CONTAINER_NAME, "trt2/Outros/" + arquivo, path)
            block_service.delete_blob(CONTAINER_NAME, blob.name)
            os.remove(path)
```

Comment: Can you post the code that you've written thus far?

Comment: Question updated

Comment: Where is the bottleneck? If those 1000 pdfs contain 80GB of data, 10 mins is fine, if its 2 MB its long - check the size against your downloadspeed and see if that is the problem. If so, upgrade or try to minimize the data volume, f.e. by zipping your millions of pdfs 1000s at a time (or 7z) to reduce the data transfered over wire. If you use wlan, get a lan connection to strip out that bottleneck, upgrate to 1000mbit lan , ... Analyze, then fix or circumvent it.

Comment: How can I zip the data in Azure using Python? Or how can I download amounts of Blobs ? Is with 'get_blob_to_stream' ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using [Azure Batch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/) for this. You can spin up 100 VMs and let them do the job. No need to download the file to your local computer.

You can also do it on a single Azure VM, but it will take longer than with Azure Batch.

In both ways the files will stay within the Azure datacenter which makes it faster and you won't have to pay for the egress traffic.